Unable to access azureml datastore
full error "Unable to access data because you do not have 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/datastores/listsecrets/action' permission in your role assignment for this workspace. Please contact your admin to assign you a role with this permission if you want to preview or access the data."
I have created a machine learning bicep file with all resources required. However getting the above error.
my bicep file contains the following i also have all required resources such as applicationInsights,containerRegistry,keyVault,storageAccount. The resources deploys successfully however when i go into azure machine learning click on datastore i get the error.
resource machineLearning 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces@2020-08-01' = {
  name: 'mlw'
  location: 'loc'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    // dependent resources
    applicationInsights: appInsights.id
    containerRegistry: containerRegistry.id
    keyVault: keyVaultId
    storageAccount: storage.id
  }
}

resource amlci 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/computes@2020-08-01' = {
  name: 'mlw-cluster'
  parent: machineLearning
  location: loc
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    computeType: 'AmlCompute'
    properties: {
      vmSize: 'Standard_DS3_v2'
      subnet: null
      osType: 'Linux'
      scaleSettings: {
        maxNodeCount: 5
        minNodeCount: 0
      }
    }
  }
}




I have contributor rights


Issue was related role which results in authentication blocker @MPathan Assign Reader or contributor roles and try again

@ Vinay B i have contributor  rights but still getting same issue added the screenshot of contributor rights to question. this is the ml workspace and also have storage with contributor

Your usage requires permission based on mutilple permission which cannot be achived using one contributor role need to create custom role based on the permission required refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-assign-roles?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=team-lead

@Vinay B is there any examples of doing this role assignments in a bicep file

Custom role should create based on the permissions/ privileges that one user possess in any organization we need to provide the permission based on that @Mpathan

You have to assign roles for the user and app both. for your bicep file you need to assign to your system assigned identity and for viewing in workspace need to assign it for yourself the user.

Self fixed adding for future reference for others as @Vinay B said assigning role assignments is required. I added the the AzureMLDataScientistRoleDefinition. This allows access to the datastore and entire workspace. the guid for this role is f6c7c914-8db3-469d-8ca1-694a8f32e121.
   @description('This is the built-in  azureml data scientist role. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles')
    resource AzureMLDataScientistRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2022-04-01' existing = {
      scope: subscription()
      name: 'f6c7c914-8db3-469d-8ca1-694a8f32e121'
    }
    
    resource AzureMLDataScientistRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
      name: guid(machineLearning.id, AzureMLDataScientistRoleDefinition.id)
      properties: {
        roleDefinitionId: AzureMLDataScientistRoleDefinition.id
        principalId:'mygroupid'
        principalType: 'Group'
      }
      //reference to your machine learning workspace
      scope: machineLearning
    }

